# Linq to Entities: how to filter using Non-Primitive types

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

EF does not allow to use Non-Primitive types in queries because they can not be translated into SQL.
And If you try you will probably get the same exception :

> 'Unable to create a constant value of type
>   'SomeType'. Only primitive
>   types or enumeration types are supported in this context.'

My question is what other options do I have for the code below:

```
public class SkillFilter
{
    public IEnumerable<EmployeeSkill> TargetSkills { get; set; }

    public IQueryable<Employee> Filter(IQueryable<Employee> employees)
    {
        return employees.Where(employee =>
            TargetSkills.Any(targetSkill => employee.Skills
                       .Any(empSkill =>
                           empSkill.SkillId == targetSkill.SkillId &&
                           empSkill.Proficiency == targetSkill.Proficiency)));


    }
}

public class EmployeeSkill
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
    public Guid SkillId { get; set; }
    public Skill Skill { get; set; }
    public SkillProficiency? Proficiency { get; set; }
}

public enum SkillProficiency
{
    Basic = 1,
    Novice = 2,
    Intermediate = 3,
    Advanced = 4,
    Expert = 5
}
```

I need to find all employees who have at least one skill from `Skills` property. And I can't use primitive type, because I need to check not only Id of a skill but also it's proficiency.

First of all - **using of ToList() is not an option**. I'm trying to find a way to filter it in database, not in memory.

Options that I have tried already:

1) Using the Contains method with IEqulityComparer. Got same error

```
    ...
return employees.Where(employee =>
                 TargetSkills.Any(targetSkill =>
                    employee.Skills.Contains(targetSkill, new EmployeeSkillComparer())));

...

public class EmployeeSkillComparer : IEqualityComparer<EmployeeSkill>
    {
        public bool Equals(EmployeeSkill x, EmployeeSkill y)
        {
            return x.SkillId == y.SkillId && x.Proficiency == y.Proficiency;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(EmployeeSkill obj)
        {
            return obj.SkillId.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

2. Using Join. Got same error.

...

```
return from e in employees
               where (from empSkill in e.Skills
                      join targetSkill in TargetSkills
                      on new {empSkill.SkillId, empSkill.Proficiency} equals 
                         new {targetSkill.SkillId, targetSkill.Proficiency}
                      select empSkill).Any()
               select e;
```

...

**EDIT**

I got few suggestions to change a type of the property **Proficiency**. 
The exception I got in the examples above said:

> 'Unable to create a constant value of type
>   'DynamicTargeting.Data.Models.Employees.**EmployeeSkill**'. Only primitive
>   types or enumeration types are supported in this context

So the problem is not in Profiency, but in the class **EmployeeSkill**. Proficiency is **enum** and it's translated to **int** without any problems.
But in order to not rely only on the exception message, I have changed it's type to a primitive one - **int**. 
Error is still the same.  Nevertheless, thank you guys for replies!

Comment: In your entity class you need to define `int` type instead of `SkillProficiency`.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn  thank you for reply, but it doesn't solve the problem. I have added a detailed answer in the Edit section.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to compare converted values of enumeration type. Try `empSkill.Proficiency.ToString() == targetSkill.Proficiency.ToString()`

Comment: thank you for reply, but it doesn't solve the problem. I have added a detailed answer in the Edit section.